# Laravel Many to Many filter with sum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I'm working in laravel and I need to filter the users who orders with certain amount of money in orders 
so I used  to filter the orders count

```
 User::where('type','client')
            ->has('orders', '>=', $min_orders)
            ->has('orders', '<=', $max_orders)
            ->withCount('orders')
        ->paginate(25)
        ;
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Your code is perfect as long as you defined `orders()` relation which is a `hasMany()` relation on User model. And to access the orders count, you will do `$user->orders_count`, that is the attribute name Laravel will add to each User model in the result Collection.

Comment: I understand now that you wanted SUM instead of COUNT. Do you want the filter after the Eloquent query execute or in the same query to apply pagination to it?

Comment: @KeitelDOG yes, that what I am aiming to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want SUM with User info then you need to GROUP BY on user info. And If you want the SUM on the Many side table, then you have to JOIN to that table. Assuming you have `orders.amount` field, you can try this :

```
<?php

User::select('user.id', 'email', 'name', 'type', \DB::raw('SUM(orders.amount) as amount_sum'))
    ->where('type','client')
    ->join('orders', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->has('orders', '>=', $min_orders)
    ->has('orders', '<=', $max_orders)
    ->withCount('orders')
    ->groupBy('user.id', 'email', 'name', 'type')
    ->havingRaw('amount_sum > ?', [50])
    ->orderBy('amount_sum', 'desc')
    ->paginate(25);
```

This way you can paginate directly into One single query results. But remember that each User column you want to use in SELECT has to be used in GROUP BY too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
$users = User::filter(function ($user) use ($min_orders, $max_orders) {
    return ($user->orders()->sum('price') >= $min_orders) && ($user->orders()->sum('price') <= $max_orders);
})->get();
```

Haven't tested, but I think it should work

Comment: You should add the variables to `$users = User::filter(function ($user) use ($min_orders, $max_orders) {...}`.

Comment: @KeitelDOG ohh right, forgot about it, edited answer

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter does not exist.